# It is possible to run multiple instance of foundation-emails?

Tags: javascript, email, laravel-5, zurb-foundation

I am working on an web app to build newsletters email, I wanna use [foundation-emails](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-emails) but I dont know if is possible to run multiple instances for build multiple email.

For example, two user use the web app and build emails at the same time.

The output must be an html file and its assets (images and files), all this in a zip.

Answer (score 0):

You could run multiple instances. However, you should be able to accomplish multiple emails that are radically different and use only one install.

I have created several different emails in the same instance that use different fonts, colors and use the same sass file, which is my only modification. I use a  different classes to match individual styles.

```
<body class="alfa">
<body class="beta">
<body class="charlie">
<body class="delta">
```

By changing the class, the entire email changes on the fly.

I created custom layouts because it's a lot easier to have specific logos and links attached to the layout and create pages for the content.